# Customize QDial with stylesheet

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets, qdial

There are comprehensive examples for style sheets of `QWidgets` [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html). Unfortunately `QDial` is missing from the examples.

Can I change the appearance (basically the color, border of the rotary knob) just by a stylesheet? In [this article](http://dronecolony.com/2012/12/11/customized-qdial-with-qss-support/) a new dial class is supporting style sheets, but can it not be done with Qt's standard class?

The slider / scrollbar examples show how every detail can be tweaked, so I wonder if there is something similar for `QDial`? I understand I can exchange the underlying image, but would prefer an easy way just to set its color, border.

I have tried the standard attributes such as `backgroud-color`, `background`, `color` with no success. Also tried `QDial::handle` , so a hint would be useful.

Comment: `QDial` does not support style sheets (here's an old bugreport https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-1160). Though it can be customized through a custom `QStyle`. Check how `QDial` looks with a new Fusion style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the background with style sheets but that appears to be it.

Perhaps things have changed since you asked the question on Jan 6, 2014 but I was able to get style sheets to work for the background only.  Everything else I tried had no effect.

Notice how the background change affects the needle too.

[image: The QDial widget rendered in FC20 under MATE using the giving stylesheet]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os
import time

class MyDial(QtGui.QDial):
    style =''' 
    QDial
    {
        background-color:QLinearGradient( 
            x1: 0.177, y1: 0.004, x2: 0.831, y2: 0.911, 
            stop: 0 white, 
            stop: 0.061 white, 
            stop: 0.066 lightgray, 
            stop: 0.5 #242424, 
            stop: 0.505 #000000,
            stop: 0.827 #040404,
            stop: 0.966 #292929,
            stop: 0.983 #2e2e2e
        );
    }
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDial, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet(self.style)

        self.setRange(0,100)
        self.setValue(0)
        self.setWrapping(True) # Smooth transition from 99 to 0
        self.setNotchesVisible(True)
```